# C# Wait for all output data from redirect output, then continue

Tags: c#, winforms, invoke

I have an application, which waits for the user's command (like cmd). When user confirms his command by pressing Enter, program starts method called *work()*. This method starts process whose output is redirected to richtextbox. I am using Invoke to write output to richtextbox in realtime. But my problem is, that output from program is displayed even after the method ends. How can I wait for the end of output and then write new line with prompt?
I welcome any advice and sorry about my english.

**CALLING METHOD**

```
if (e.KeyChar == (char)13) //Enter
{
     work();
     richTextBoxOutput.AppendText(prompt + " ");
}
```

**METHOD WORK()**

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = command;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments; 
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory; 
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; 

            proc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(
            (s, e) =>
            {
                if (richTextBoxOutput.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    richTextBoxOutput.Invoke(new Action(() => richTextBoxOutput.AppendText(e.Data + "\n")));
                }
                else
                    richTextBoxOutput.AppendText(e.Data + "\n");
            }
        );
            proc.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((s, e) => { richTextBoxOutput.AppendText(e.Data + "\n"); });

            proc.Start();
            proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
            this.setTitle("Working ...");
            while (!proc.HasExited)
            {
                Application.DoEvents(); // This keeps your form responsive by processing events                
            }
```